# How to do runtime checks in a xamarin forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have read the Xamarin.Android documentation about performing runtime checks but the problem is i'm dealing with a xamarin forms project.

Most of my code and ui is in my PCL(Public Class library)Project, so how can i know or determine what  apis are being used and the api levels they belong to they are. For example how  can i write a runtime check that only loads specific apis if the device is running Lollipop or above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DeviceInfo](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin).

```
var version = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.VersionNumber;
```